# Changing encryption cipher and method in CodeIgniter encrypt class, changes globally the settings?

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

i have the following class in CodeIgniter

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 
class ZoEncryption {

public $_CI;
public function __construct() {
    $this->_CI = & get_instance();
    $this->_CI->encrypt->set_cipher(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH);
    $this->_CI->encrypt->set_mode(MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
}
function encode($str, $key) {
    return $this->_CI->encrypt->encode($str, $key);
}
function decode($str, $key) {
    return $this->_CI->encrypt->decode($str, $key);
    }
}

?>
```

I am using this library in my ci application to encrypt and decrypt user content in the database. I am specifying the cipher and the mode as i want to have specific logic in encryption/decryption and i dont want surprises in the future if the coding of this change.

Also i am using [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library in order to implement early the new password hashing schema of PHP 5.5.

This library allows for me to build my user password hashing logic based on the future of PHP.

**If i dont set the cipher and mode in the constructor and put the relevant lines in my base controller constructor then my password hashing does not work.**

**Specifically if i put the following two lines in MY_Controller, the password verification doesn't work.**

Do the following lines affect CI globally?

```
$CI->encrypt->set_cipher(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH);

$CI->encrypt->set_mode(MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't change the global settings. It will only affect the code directly attached to where you define it.

If you want the changes to be global, you will either have to hack the core, [create a library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html), or [override/extend](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html) the core.

Comment: But as i say, it does change something. I will emphasize on my question what my problem is.

Comment: If you don't explicitly set the cipher and mode CI will use the defaults. If you encode something with the defaults, you can not decode them with other ciphers or modes. It is far more likely that your library is breaking things and not that you set the cipher and mode in CI.

Comment: But if i dont specify the mode and cipher in my top controller the lib works fine. and its quite famous lib for bringing the 5.5 password hashing feature to older versions...

Comment: If you are using the library for encryption, why does it matter what the CI cipher is set to? Either use the library for encryption or use CI's encryption. It doesn't make sense to mix the two...

Comment: Please if you take a look at : https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php and you will see that for <5.5 php version is the only way to implement the future of php  password hashing that will be implemented in 5.5, and that is the reason i want to use it...

Comment: That's fine -- use it. But don't try to mix it with CodeIgniter's encryption. Just use `$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);` or whatever function from the library you need. https://www.google.com/search?q=codeigniter+third+party+library http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: What i didnt get is that setting $CI->encrypt->set_cipher(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH); i wouldnt expect to affect the third party library...

Comment: It shouldn't. However, in your `ZoEncryption` class, you are not using the library, you are using CI encryption. Use the library for everything or use CI encryption for everything.